# Azure Function Managed Identity to Azure Sql - Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I have a C# dotnet core 3.1 Azure Function App (named func-utrngen-dev-001) that I'd like to configure to authenticate to a Sql Azure database via managed identity.

Steps Taken:

1. Created the AAD admin for sql server account
2. Used that account to open a connection to the sql server
3. Ran the following to created a "contained user" of the same name as the azure function app

   CREATE USER [func-utrngen-dev-001] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER

   ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [func-utrngen-dev-001]

   ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [func-utrngen-dev-001]
4. Ensured that "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" is set to "Yes" from the Azure Portal under the Sql Server\Security\Firewalls and virtual networks blas
5. Ensured that System assigned\Status is set to "On" on the function app's Identity blade

When the function app attempts to authenticate, I get the following error:

> Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

So I installed Microsoft's "MSI Validator" tool and ran through the steps described [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/managed-identity-for-azure-app-services/bc-p/2594171#M445).
I ran the following from the Powershell window of a Kudu session:

> ./msi-validator.exe test-connection -r sql -e "Data Source=sql-utrngen-dev-001.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=utrngen;"

It successfully obtained a token but then failed with the same error as my function app:

> Unable to connect to SQL. Exception : Login failed for user
> '<token-identified principal>'

6. I ran select * FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file(path to tsql audit blob) but the results only showed activity from my account logged into SSMS

What should I try next?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fix was to give the correct name for the database ‍♂️. More haste less speed

Comment: Ran across the same 'issue'. When a user only has access to a specific database instead of the whole server, connecting without an explicitly specified database name throws the `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'` error.